# Randomly pick elements from an array

Tags: java

This is a part of creating a matching game with graphical components. I need to code a class method named randomOrder. I should be able to randomly choose which pictures to be used and I need to place them randomly on the board (for now the board is a 4x4).

I want a method that randomly moves around the elements in an array. For this I wrote

```
public class Tools {

   public static void randomOrder(Object[] f){


      Object[] a = new Object[8];
   }
}
```

The only thing I got from the hint is the following:

"*Use a temporary array inside the method and take one element at a time from the original array and place it in the temporary array. If the array-position is taken, then you need to randomize a new position. When all the elements are placed, you can copy the temporary array to the original.*"

I don't understand how to use the hint. I feel this is so complicated that I can't even formulate a proper question.

1. Can someone translate the hint to me in a more understandable
   question?
2. Is my start okay?

I'm sorry if the question is bad, I don't know how to make it better. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try:

> Use a temporary array inside the method

You already did that, although the array `a` should have the same length as `f`

> take one element at a time from the original array and place it in the temporary array

You iterate over `a` and for each index you do the following:

Create a random integer between 0 and the size of the array, e.g. for a 4x4 grid your array would have length 16 so the index would be between 0 and 15 (both inclusive).

Get the element at that index from `f` and place it at the current position in `a`. Then set that index in `f` to `null`.

Example:

```
//iterate
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) { 
  int random = ...; //create the random number here
  Object o = f[random];

  while( o == null ) {
    //see below
  }

  a[i] = o;
}
```

> If the array-position is taken, then you need to randomize a new position.

If the element in `f` already is null then either create a new random number (that's what the text hints at) or increment that index until you hit the end or find a non-null element (probably better from a performance point of view, when you hit the end go back to index 0 for `f`).

> When all the elements are placed, you can copy the temporary array to the original.

When you are done filling `a` you iterate once again and set the elements in `f` according to their index in `a`, i.e.

```
for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) { 
  f[i] = a[i];
}
```